# Is there any explanation for the formation of "bomphiologia" as a Greek word for "verborum bombus"?

Tags: etymology, greek, rhetoric

Recently on ELU, a question was asked about the meaning of three rhetorical terms that are obviously based on Greek: [“macrologia”, “periergia” and “bomphiologia”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/446528/difference-in-meaning-and-usage-between-macrologia-periergia-and-bomphiolo).

The Greek etymologies of "[macrologia](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/M/macrologia.htm)" and "[periergia](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/P/periergia.htm)" seem fairly straightforward and are summarized by the *Silva Rhetoricae* (Gideon Burton, [rhetoric.byu.edu](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/)) entries referenced in the linked post, but Burton does not provide any etymology for "[bomphiologia](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/B/bomphiologia.htm)".

Based on my research so far, it appears that the earliest known occurrence of this word is in Richard Sherry's *[Treatise of Schemes and Tropes](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Primary%20Texts/Sherry.htm)* (1550, 1555). For context, Sherry seems to systematically give two versions of each rhetorical term, one in Greek and one in Latin. "Bomphiologia" is presented as the Greek equivalent of Latin "Verborum bombus".  There is a suggestive similarity between the first parts of ***bom***bus and ***bom***phiologia, but I don't know of any reason why the second "b" of *bombus* would change to "ph" in a longer word, and through Google Books, I found a footnote about the term *bomphiologia* that seems to present even more words with related meanings and similar forms:

> "Bomphiologia, or Pompous Speech" [*in right margin*]
>
> Others there be that fall into the contrary vice by using such bombasted<sup>66</sup> words, as seem altogether farced<sup>67</sup> full of wind, being a great deal too high and lofty for the matter, whereof ye may find too many in all popular rhymers.<sup>68</sup>
>
> [*Editorial footnotes:*]
>
> 66. **bombasted** stuffed, as with padding.
> 67. **farced** stuffed (a cooking term).
> 68. On *bomphiologia*, see Sherry 61. Sherry appears to be coining this term, which he also calls *verborum bombus* (booming words) and exemplifies by reference to Terence's braggart soldier. This is probably a slip for Plautus' Pyrgopolinices, the title character in the *Miles Gloriosus*, who refers to a commander of his named Bombomachides ("booming fighter," 1.14).

—*[The Art of English Poesy, Critical Edition](https://books.google.com/books?id=MPVrKXncybgC&pg=PA345&dq=%22bomphiologia%22#v=onepage&q=%22bomphiologia%22&f=false)* (original by George Puttenham, 1590; edited by Frank Whigham and Wayne A. Rebhorn, 2007), p. 345

Based on this passage, I'm wondering if *bomphiologia* was perhaps originally associated with words like *pomp(ous)* and *bombast,* or the name *Bombomachides* (which is ultimately related to the noun *bombus*).

To summarize, here are the three apparently distinct Greek roots that seem to me like they might possibly be relevant:

1. #### Greek *βόμβος* (as in Latin "bombus")

   The Latin word *bombus* seems to be from Ancient Greek *βόμβος,* which is also the first element in the name *Bombomachides* that occurs in Plautus's play about a boastful soldier, *Miles Gloriosus* (but not as the name of the title character).
2. #### Greek *βόμβυξ* (as in English "bombast")

   The Oxford English Dictionary tells me that English *bombast,* a variant of *bombace,* has an etymology that does ultimately go back to Greek, but that doesn't seem to have any certain connection to *bombus*:

   > < Old French *bombace* cotton, cotton wadding < late Latin *bombāce-m,* accusative of *bombax* cotton, a corruption and transferred use of Latin *bombyx* silk, < Greek *βόμβυξ* silkworm, silk.

   The association of the English word "bombast" with "turgid language" seems to have existed at least as early as 1589, according to the OED:

   > 1589   T. Nashe *To Students* in R. Greene *Menaphon* Epist. sig. **   To outbraue better pens with the swelling **bumbast** of a bragging blanke verse.

   I don't know if we have any evidence of similar metaphorical uses of a word like *bombacem* or *bombacium* in the Latin of this century. I guess this root is technically *bombyc-* or *bombac-,* with a final velar that would have to be truncated to serve as as base for *bomphiologia,* but the formation of the rhetorical term seems irregular in any case, so I'm not sure I can rule out the possibility of some kind of truncation like that.
3. #### Greek *πομπή* (as in Latin "pompa", English "pomp")

   The OED says the word "pomp" also has a Greek origin, which unsuprisingly seems to be separate from the origin of *βόμβος* or *βόμβυξ*:

   > classical Latin *pompa* ceremonial procession, ostentation, display < ancient Greek *πομπή* a sending away, solemn procession, parade, display < *πέμπειν* to send, of unknown origin.

I don't know whether there are any other possible Greek roots that might be relevant.

Does anyone know of any further information that would shed light on the etymology of this rhetorical term? Can anyone think of an explanation for the "ph" (and the following "i") in *bomphiologia*? Of course, it's impossible to go back in time and look into Sherry's head to see what he was thinking when he coined the word (if that is what happened), but I thought it seemed possible that someone here would know something that might provide useful context that would increase my understanding of how the word might have been formed.

Comment: Not Greek, but a Latin root that might have caught Sherry's attention. *Hio* gape; in Smith's used to mean incoherent, disconnected. *Hiandus* - bawling, yelling. Also *mp* is found in the modern Greek for a bar: Μπαρ this is simply aspirated.

Comment: Two suggestions: could it be a misprint/misspelling? Perhaps it was meant to be _bomphiLologia_ or even _bomphiLogia_? Note that _homeoteleuton_ is misspelled  twice ( _homotelento_  and _homoteleto_) in Sherry's book. Or perhaps it's a joke? Perhaps _bomphiologia_ is in fact an example of _bomphiologia_ - both hollow noise (_bombus_) and padded bluster (_bombast_)? It does seem that Sherry's whole project was experimental to some extent (see: H. W. Hildebrandt, "Sherry: Renaissance rhetorician", 1960)

Comment: With regard to the joke thesis: the example of the 'boasting souldiar [sic]' that Sherry points to is about his 'great gasyng wordes [sic]', not explicitly the name he references ('Bombomachides'). To this end, the opening exchange of the _Miles Gloriosus_ has the braggart soldier rattle off imaginary names (Bombomachides being only one) to which the slave says, in an aside (and I paraphrase), "none of which ever existed". Thus, _bomphiologia_ may itself be a "great gasyng worde", empty but for hot air. Perhaps.